# What is the difference between "adab" and "behavior"?

Tags: arabic, adab, behavior

There's some overlap between the word "adab" and "behavior", but I'm not sure if all proper Muslim behavior is considered "adab".

> Adab in the context of behavior, refers to prescribed Islamic etiquette: "refinement, good manners, morals, decorum, decency, humaneness".  While interpretation of the scope and particulars of Adab may vary among different cultures, common among these interpretations is regard for personal standing through the observation of certain codes of behavior. To exhibit Adab would be to show "proper discrimination of correct order, behavior, and taste." -- [Adab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adab_(Islam)), Wikipedia

Wikipedia lists some examples, but they seem to refer to relatively minor, short-term behaviors (saying Bismillah, cutting nails, etc.), which makes me think that "adab" is a subset of Muslim behaviors.

**Question**: What is the difference between "adab" and "behavior"?

The motivation behind the question is that I created the [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior) tag, but I'm worried it's a synonym of the tag [adab](/questions/tagged/adab).

Ideally, it'd be nice to have some examples of Muslims behaviors that would not be considered "adab" if they're different.

Comment: Possibly related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/what-is-the-difference-between-akhlaq-and-adab